Issue with Google Earth Engine Plugin in QGIS
I am trying to resolve an error from using the Python console on QGIS. I have QGIS version
QGIS version 3.34.4-Prizren on my linux Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, Codename-Jammy. Then I successfully installed earthengine-api via my terminal, which was followed by proper authentication using earthengine authenticate.
Then I searched for Earth Engine Plugin on QGIS and I installed it. When I tried to import ee, I got the following errors below:
``` Python Console
 # Use iface to access QGIS API interface or type '?' for more info
 # Security warning: typing commands from an untrusted source can harm your computer
 import ee
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
 exec(code, self.locals)
 File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/home/taiwoo/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/
 plugins/ee_plugin/__init__.py", line 32, in __wrapping_ee_import__
 _module_ = __builtin_import__(name, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 892, in _import
 mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ee/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
 from ee import _utils
 File"/home/taiwoo/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/
 plugins/ee_plugin/__init__.py", line 34, in __wrapping_ee_import__
 if not _module_.data._credentials:
 AttributeError: partially initialized module 'ee' has no attribute 'data' (most 
 likely due to a circular import)```

In addition, I read the thread provided here https://github.com/gee-community/qgis-earthengine-plugin/issues/133,but I could not reach a solution. I also tried the following code: export PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/qgis/share/qgis/python and export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin/qgis/lib, but no hope. I still got the same error in when I tried to import ee in QGIS.

Is the problem with the QGIS/Python interface?  What if you open Python in the terminal and enter import ee there?  Do you still get the error message?

The problem is with the QGIS/Python console. I did not experience this problem when I enter import ee on my ubuntu Python terminal.
